# Probability Density Function Integration Question

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

So this question is almost exactly the same as a few others on here but the vital piece of information I need is missing. Consider an RV X with a pdf:

$f(x) = xe^{−x^2/2} $   if   $ x\gt 0$ 
 $f(x) = 0$ otherwise

So, another question on here has this exact same function but instead of a $ \gt $ there is a $ \ge$.

I've calculated the integral and my question is this: What are the terminals of the integrand? That is, where should I evaluate my final integral.

I know that if it was $f(x) = ... , x \ge 0$ I set the terminals to $0$ and infinity, does that change now that I only have a greater than sign?

Comment: Makes no difference, because for any $a$ we have $\Pr(X=a)=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow?

Comment: If density function specifies $x\gt 0$, you integrate over the same interval as when it specifies $x\ge 0$.

Comment: okay thankyou! -------

Comment: André is right, but in addition in this case it doesn't even make a difference in $f$, which is $0$ at $x=0$ in both cases.